# Distinct для двух баз одним запросом

Tags: sql, база-данных

SELECT *
FROM db1.dbo.t1 A
  JOIN db2.dbo.t2 B ON A.col1=B.col1

как можно сформировать запрос с distinct для A.col1

Comment: а чем `select distinct A.col1` не нравится ? уточните вопрос

Comment: хватал ошибку таким запросом

Comment: Какую ошибку ? это нормальная конструкция, работать обязана